# Powershell file row starts in 'String' and ends in 'Integer'

Tags: powershell, startswith, ends-with

I am reading a text file where I need to filter out and perform some formatting if a row starts in a string and ends in a number. If i had known/fix values, I could use StartWith or EndsWith to filter this line.
I tried using it as below but I guess that's wrong as it didn't work.

```
if(($record.StartsWith.GetType() -eq [string]) -and  ($record.EndsWith.GetType() -eq [int]))
```

**Example**: My rows read

```
TransDate,Merchant,Amount
Doe,Jane, *6098
3/4/2020,Walmart,6.45
3/4/2020,Starbucks,14.45
Doe,John, *6096
3/4/2020,Amazon,34.45
```

I need to be identify that row 2 and 5 have my card numbers. How can I identify these in powershell? Let me know please. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to identify the rows you're after ... a simple version could look like this:

```
$Content = Get-Content D:\sample\TextFile.txt
foreach($record in $Content){
    if($record -match '^[a-z].*\d$'){
        $record
    }
}
```